# Seekbar progress isn't destroyed when activity is rotated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

I place a discrete seekbar in my layout. When I run my code in the emulator and rotate the screen, the activity gets destroyed, but for some reason the seekbar progress stays the same. Why does this happen, shouldn't the progress be reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in Android View widgets such as `TextView`, `EditText` and `SeekBar` have their state automatically saved and restored when the device configuration changes (in your case, when you rotate the screen), provided they have an id.

That's why your `SeekBar`'s progress is not reset when the screen is rotated.

If you'd like to disable this behavior, you can add `android:saveEnabled="false"` to your view definition in XML.